# Copy reference to class member resource

Tags: c++

I have a class defined like:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void ReturnReferenceToMember(???)
    {
         ??? // Give caller a reference to member variable m_x             
    }
private: 
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m_x;
}
```

What's the C++ way to implement the ????

I don't want to copy the internals of the map, and I also want to keep being able to use the map inside the class. I don't understand move mechanics that well, but it seems to me like the second requirement negates std::move...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to pass a reference that can be changed.  That would mean passing a pointer to a reference, or a reference to a reference - both of those are invalid in C++.

The usual approach is to `return` a reference, not (since it can't be done) to pass one in the hope of it being changed.

```
std::unordered_map<int, int>& ReturnReferenceToMember()
{
     return m_x;
}
```

If you expect to pass an argument that can be changed in order to permit the caller to access class internals, it is necessary to use a pointer to a pointer

```
// double indirection needed as pointers are passed by value too

void ReturnPointerToMember(std::unordered_map<int, int> **p) 
{
    *p = &mx;
}
```

or a reference to a pointer

```
void ReturnPointerToMember(std::unordered_map<int, int> *&p)
{
    p = &mx;    // note the missing asterisk compared with passing pointer to pointer
}
```

If you don't wish the caller to change class internals, it is necessary to `const`-qualify the above in various ways.

Answer (score 2):

```
void ReturnReferenceToMember(std::unordered_map<int, int>** outMap)
{
    *outMap = &m_x;
}

void ReturnReferenceToMember(const std::unordered_map<int, int>** outMap) const
{
    *outMap = &m_x;
}
```

I overloaded it on `const` intentionally, so you can use either form depending on whether the `Foo` you have is `const`.

As you can see, we are not really using references here, because those cannot be reseated, but the caller can still use them:

```
std::unordered_map<int, int>* mapPtr = nullptr;
ReturnReferenceToMember(&mapPtr);
if (mapPtr)
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int>& mapRef = *mapPtr;
    // now you have your reference
}
```

Comment: I simplified my example too much. The return type is used up by HRESULT (Windows thing), so I need m_x to be a parameter.